# linqpad merge of lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following query

```
from c in Customers
where c.salary == "2000"
select new
    {
      c.Id,
      c.Name,
      c.Salary
    }
```

The output is

ID Name Salary

Id-9395 Ralph 2000
Id-14591    Ramesh
Id-7958 Rakesh
Id-15784    Ram

The salary is same for all 
I want it to be displayed for all id's. The output has to look like below.

ID Name Salary

Id-9395 Ralph 2000

Id-14591    Ramesh 2000

Id-7958 Rakesh 2000

Id-15784    Ram 2000

How do i do this?

Comment: What happens if you run the same query in SQL? Select Id,Name,Salary from Customers where salary = '2000'? Assuming your getting this data from SQL of course.

Comment: @sneakthief : No its not the original query. Its a modified version for generic use. 'S' is capital. Chris: No i am not getting this data from SQL. I am getting it from odata.

Comment: Is the oData service returning the right data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, although it is no different from the query you already have:

```
var customers = Customers.Select(x=> new {x.Id,x.Name,x.Salary}).
                  Where(x=>x.Salary == "2000");
```

When I run the above, I get the result you want.  I also get the same result when I run:

```
var customers= from c in Customers
            where c.Salary == "2000"
            select new
                 {
                 c.Id,
                 c.Name,
                 c.Salary
                 };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a deeper problem but you could do this:

```
from c in new Customers
let sal = "2000"
where c.Salary == sal
select new
{
     c.Id,
     c.Name,
     sal
};
```